# Oracle Rest Data Services PDF Printing error

Tags: sql, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

I have installed Oracle apex and Oracle rest data services 19.1. 
The issue i have, when i download my Interactive reports through pdf, they work fine. But when i try to use the report query | layout and generate a pdf report i get a corrupt pdf report. when i open the pdf in Notepad it shows error "**string out of range -1**" . 
Running Oracle database 12c , the reports layout works fine on apex.oracle.com but it does not work on premise. I used both rtf and xslt templates, both give an error. but, when i use generic layout i get a pdf but with no data, only shows a highlighted "**null**".

Comment: It's a feature with limited functionality, and limited shelf life. I think it will complain like this when there are too many columns, for instance. That said, there may be another cause in this case.

Comment: thanks @Scott , i will play around more, Been at it for a month now. Third party solutions are too expensive for me, thinking of creating my own solution, that's if i can't get this one to work. Regards